# Highcharts menus bottom into right side of the graph

Tags: highcharts

I have highchart like **[this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend)**.
How can I move the legends (*Firefox,IE,chrome...*) to the right of the chart?

*P.S. I am not familiar with jQuery.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **[`legend.align`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#)** option to `'right'`

```
  legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: 0,
            y: -10
          },
```

**[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QQk8Z/)**. I just tweaked it with the above mentioned code.

I Hope **[Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)** would be of great help to you, to explore the options available to personalize your charts.

Comment: Jugal Thakkar, Thanks really its excellent. thanks for your solution

Comment: i have one more question, how to display the legend text in next row if the text is too long??

Comment: @Raj solution is by Gopinagh, so you should thank him. Also please mark the answer as accepted if it helped. I see you have posted a new question which is how you should address more queries and not as comments, so great going. Welcome to SO

Comment: @Raj Glad that the answer helped you. You are welcome. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @gopi can sent me the solution for my next question

Comment: @Raj: Consider posting it as a new question. It makes your needs visible to everyone at SO, so that someone can actually come up with a better solution or it may be useful for someone else actually with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `legend: { align: 'right' }` So you can align your legend on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Vs3/), it aligns the legend on the right side.

The following have been added:

```
legend: {
    width:180, align: 'right',  
    itemWidth: 180, verticalAlign: 'middle',
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
```

Comment: i have one more question, how to display the legend text in next row if the text is too long??